# How can I attach a custom form to a Workfront user with the API?

Tags: workfront-api

I have a requirement to insert new Workfront users through the API, which I am able to do. However, I need to update a Custom Form item with an employee id. With a new user, the Custom Form must be attached before the employee id can be update. I am using the following url to attach the form:

```
https://<url>/attask/api/user/<userguid>?sessionID=<sessionid>&updates={'objectCategories':[{'categoryID': '225845d1800010d52527455df2a27f0fe2','categoryOrder':0,'objCode':'CTGY'}]}&method=put
```

The result is a HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Is it even possible to attach a Custom Form to a user? Or is there another way that it can be done through the API?

Comment: I found the answer to my issue by using the API Version in the URL. V4.0 of the API does not support attaching Custom Forms to a user, but V5.0 and above does.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I had to work through the exact same question. You are correct in your update that you need to use the most recent version of the API (as of this post, that would be 6.0) but for others who are wondering, the syntax is as follows:

`https://<url>/attask/api/v6.0/USER/<userID>?apiKey=<key>&updates={"objectCategories":[{"categoryID":"<customFormID>","categoryOrder":0,"objCode":"CTGY"}]}&method=put`